# OpenCV Error: Image step is wrong () in cvInitMatHeader

Tags: opencv, cv-bridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Name : left_mat_
Details:{flags = 1124007936, dims = 2, rows = 480, cols = 752, data = 0x80b6bc8 023"..., dataend = 0x8110bb8 "", datalimit = 0x8110bc8 "", allocator = 0x0, size = {p = 0xbffff238}, **step = {p = 0xbffff260, buf = {768, 1}}}**
Default:{...}
Decimal:{...}
Hex:{...}
Binary:{...}

This is from grabbing my image from a focus robotics stereo cam then I use stereo bridge and get this

Name : left_image_
Details:{*vptr.Image* = 0x80840e8, header = {*vptr.Header* = 0x8084128, seq = 0, stamp = {<ros::TimeBase<ros::Time, ros::Duration>> = {sec = 0, nsec = 0}, }, frame_id = {static npos = 4294967295, _M_dataplus = {std::allocator<char> = {<__gnu_cxx::new_allocator> = {}, }, _M_p = 0x808f5fc ""}}, _*connection_header = {px = 0x0, pn = {pi* = 0x0}}}, height = 480, width = 752, encoding = {static npos = 4294967295, _M_dataplus = {std::allocator<char> = {<__gnu_cxx::new_allocator> = {}, }, _M_p = 0x808f5fc ""}}, is_bigendian = 0 '\000', **step = 768**, data = {<std::_Vector_base<unsigned char, std::allocator >> = {_M_impl = {<std::allocator> = {<__gnu_cxx::new_allocator> = {}, }, _M_start 023"..., _M_finish = 0x8252c00 "", _M_end_of_storage = 0x8252c00 ""}}, }, _*connection_header = {px = 0x0, pn = {pi* = 0x0}}}
Default:{...}
Decimal:{...}
Hex:{...}
Binary:{...}
Octal:{...}

When I try and run image viewer I get the error in the title what is going wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12780/opencv-error:-image-step-is-wrong-()-in-cvinitmatheader/) by [wyosae67](https://answers.ros.org/users/1693/wyosae67/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2012-01-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

just had to change it to lower case mono8.

---

Originally posted by [wyosae67](https://answers.ros.org/users/1693/wyosae67/) with karma: 76 on 2012-01-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0